# How to generate multiple man pages?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, manpage

I have a command line program written in Python. I would like to generate man pages with Sphinx.

I would like to have one page by commands like:

`man myprog foo` --> redirect to the man page of the `foo` command.

`man myprog foo2` --> redirect to the man page of the `foo2` command.

etc.

The problem is Sphinx generates only **one** man page with the aggregation of all man pages.

How can I have my expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Given the structure

```
    docs/
    docs/source
    docs/source/conf.py
    docs/source/manable1/includable.rst
    docs/source/index.rst
```

Then, if you are in docs type

```
    sphinx-build -b man -c source  source/manable1/ man/other_man
```

you can automate that by either patching the makefile or a one liner in bash

```
    for i in source/man*; do
            sphinx-build -b man -c source  $i man/$( basename $i );
    done
```

(not tested but should be close)

beware the include path, the relatives, the cross reference....

It might limit what you can do in Rst

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand the man/other_man argument.  What it is ?

Comment: just a way to structure your directory with each independant manual. the structure would be much more man/sub_topic where sub topic handles all the revelant files for a given topic.